# How to build a miniprogram (aka, tinyapp) framework in an app?

Tags: android, ios, wechat-miniprogram

Mini-program (tiny-app) is a very convenient and successful way to enrich the content and functions in an app, it’s ability to enrich an app’s ecosystem has been proven in China’s WeChat and AliPay apps.

We would like to embed such functionality in our app. However, most of the materials that can be searched on the web is about how to build/develop a mini-program instead of how to build such a framework in an app, both for Android and iOS.

Is there any material/document about **how to build a mini-program framework in an app?** (NOT how to build a mini-program)

Comment: It sounds like you want to design an architecture that enables your app to support its own mini programs. To narrow down the scope, will these mini programs only be made by you, or do you plan on allowing third parties to write their own mini programs for your app? And is it sufficient that all your mini programs come already included in your app, or do you require them to be selectively downloaded through your app?

Comment: @PeterParker Yes, I want to support mini programs in my app. The mini programs can be made by us or by the third parties. In theory, the mini program should be package as a file on a CDN with some meta info. The mini program should be downloaded and launched when some user click the link/button accessing the mini program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the solution I am looking for is actually NOT a mini-program "FRAMEWORK" but a mini-program "ENGINE". A mini-program framework refers to something that helps the development of mini-programs, including some libraries, UI components, maybe even a IDE. Instead, a mini-program engine is a component which we can integrate into our app, so that it downloads packages of different business from remote URLs and executes them.

After I changed my search keyword to "mini-program engine", the results pop out. The following is some open source projects related to mini-program engine I found:

1. https://github.com/weidian-inc/hera
2. https://github.com/githubliruiyuan/HybridFlutter

Answer (score 3):

This is the GitHub link maybe it will be useful for you
https://github.com/apelegri/wechat-mini-program-wiki